# Combining multiple queries into an output

Tags: php, mysql

With a feedback survey they can select bad, neutral or good.  I want to compile the bad and good into a table.
I am trying to create a tally "table" output from an ajax request to replace a div content.
Ideally it will look like:

| Experience | Negative | Positive |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cleanliness | 12 | 18 |
| Check-In/Out | 4 | 30 |
| Food | 2 | 12 |
| Staff | 1 | 8 |

So my mysql has columns for cleanliness, food, etc.  Inside is ratings of negative/neutral/positive.

I thought of using a single php script to populate the table, and came up with this so far:

I make two queries:

```
$pos = $pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(IF(Cleanliness = 'positively', 1, NULL)) AS Cleanliness, 
                        COUNT(IF(Check-In/Out = 'positively', 1, NULL)) AS Check-In/Out, 
                        COUNT(IF(Food = 'positively', 1, NULL)) AS Food, 
                        COUNT(IF(Staff = 'positively', 1, NULL)) AS Staff 
                    FROM responses");

$neg = $pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(IF(Cleanliness = 'negatively', 1, NULL)) AS Cleanliness, 
                        COUNT(IF(Check-In/Out = 'negatively', 1, NULL)) AS Check-In/Out, 
                        COUNT(IF(Food = 'negatively', 1, NULL)) AS Food, 
                        COUNT(IF(Staff = 'negatively', 1, NULL)) AS Staff 
                    FROM responses");
```

Then fetch them:

```
$positives = $pos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$negatives = $neg->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Now, they are arrayed but how to assemble both in an output?  I can't Key => Value => Value right?

```
foreach (array_combine($positives, $negatives) as $pos => $neg) {
    echo "$neg - $pos <br>";
}
```

So I get my negative and positive but now no row "title".
If I just output the array, I can get the row title but only one of the counts.

Should I scrap trying to combine in a single script and create a "generic" script and POST the column and desired response for just a single count output?  That will be a lot of ajax queries hitting the same php script.

Thanks!

SQL fiddle, not sure how to make the right side do what my php is doing with PDO.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37c0c2e/7

Comment: Can probably be done with a single query. Can you create an SQL fiddle?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37c0c2e/5/0 added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could obtain the table using  a single UNION query

```
SELECT 'staff', COUNT(IF(`staff` = 'negative', 1, NULL)) negative, COUNT(IF(`staff` = 'positive', 1, NULL)) positive
FROM responses 
UNION 
SELECT 'cleanliness', COUNT(IF(`cleanliness` = 'negative', 1, NULL)) negative, COUNT(IF(`cleanliness` = 'positive', 1, NULL)) positive
FROM responses 
UNION 

SELECT 'food', COUNT(IF(`food` = 'negative', 1, NULL)) negative, COUNT(IF(`food` = 'positive', 1, NULL)) positive
FROM responses 
UNION
SELECT 'check-in/out', COUNT(IF(`check-in/out` = 'negative', 1, NULL)) negative, COUNT(IF(`check-in/out` = 'positive', 1, NULL)) positive
FROM responses
```

Comment: I then ran a loop to spit out the results.
foreach ($table as $row) 
    { 
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['staff'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['negative'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['positive'] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

Thanks, scaisEdge